# The boundary of $[y:|y_i - x_i | < \eta, i \le k]$ in the product metric space $R^\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

The following is an excerpt from Billingsley's Convergence of Probability Measures. In the example, $R^\infty$ is the countable product space of $R$ given the metric $\rho(x,y)=\sum_i b(x_i,y_i)/2^i$ where $b(x,y)=1 \wedge |x-y|$. $R_f^\infty$ is the class of all sets of the form $\pi_k^{-1}H$ for $H \in R^k$. In this example, it says for $A_\eta = [y:|y_i - x_i | < \eta, i \le k]$, $\partial A_\eta$ consists of the points $y$ such that $|y_i - x_i | \le \eta$ for all $i \le k$, with equality for some $i$. I cannot figure out why this is so, as I thought they should be those $y$ of the form $|y_i - x_i|=\eta$ for $i \le k$. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could explain this part to me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that $y
 \in \partial A_{\eta}$ implies $|y_i-x_i| \leq \eta$ for all $i \leq k$. If strict inequality holds for every $i$ then we can find $\delta >0$ such that $|z_i-y_i| <\delta$ for $i \leq k$ implies $z \in A_{\eta}$. This means there is an open neighborhood of $y$ which is contained in $A_{\eta}$ contradicting the fact that $y$ is a boundary point. Hence equality must hold for some $i$. Conversely, suppose $|y_i-x_i| \leq \eta$ for al $i \leq k$ and $|y_j-x_j| =\eta$ for some $j$. Then, by replacing $y_j$ by $y_j \pm \epsilon$ with $\epsilon >0 $ sufficiently small (and keeping other $y_i$'s unchanged)  we can approximate $y$ points from inside $A$ as well as points from outside $A$, so $y$ is a boundary point.

Comment: Why does $y \in \partial A_\eta$ imply $|y_i - x_i| \le \eta$ for all $i \le k$? I can't see why this should not imply $|y_i - x_i| = \eta$ for all $i$\le k$.

Comment: Compare with the following: what is the boundary of $\{(x,y): 0 \leq x \leq 1,0\leq y \leq 1\}$?  Not every point point on the boundary has $x,y$ both having the extreme values $0$ and $1$, right? These extreme values give only the verticies of the square not the sides of the square.  Similary we need not have equality for all points on the boundary in this case.